# How to fill the selection to sublimeText3 ctrl+p overlay?

Tags: sublimetext

In`\Sublime Text Build 3065 x64\Data\Packages\Default\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap`:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+p"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true} },
```

I want to select a text ( file path ) and press ctrl + p to fill it to the popup panel.

After Modified( but doesn't work)：

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+p"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true, "text": "${0:$SELECTION}"} }
```

Comment: [Build 3114](https://sublimetext.com/3) is the latest public build, and [Build 3117](https://sublimetext.com/3dev) is the latest dev build. Build 3065 was released nearly two years ago. I **strongly** suggest you upgrade. For a portable install, first close Sublime, unzip the new portable build someplace, and copy the contents of the root directory (`sublime_text.exe`, `python33.zip`, etc.) over the contents of your current root directory. Finally, delete your old `Packages` directory (**not** `Data/Packages`) and copy over `Packages` from the new directory.

Comment: Alternatively, simply unzip the new portable install wherever you want, and copy over the `Data` hierarchy from the old location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The placeholders can not applied to every sublime command, but must be supported by the command. However you can easily write your own plugin to get your behavior

Open `Tools >> Developer >> New Plugin...`, paste, and save:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class ShowGotoOverlayWithSelectionCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        window = self.window
        view = window.active_view()
        text = view.substr(view.sel()[0])
        window.run_command("show_overlay", {
            "overlay": "goto",
            "show_files": True,
            "text": text
        })
```

Afterwards open your keymap and add the command:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+p"], "command": "show_goto_overlay_with_selection" },
```

Comment: Is there some way to have the text selected? Many times I forger I have something selected when I do crtl+p, if it were selected I can just press backspace and go. Thanks

Comment: @gae123 You can just add a line with the content `window.run_command("select_all")`.